# limit to 10 results using redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I wanted to know how to have a 10 result limit on a redis query. Im using a node js library , and streamline.js.

basically, i do hgetall as a command but the docs state that the "SORT" command has an option for LIMIT. I was just wondering if there was any way to apply a limit in redis. Here is a sample of one of the queries:

```
members.hgetall(All,_);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HGETALL` retrieves all members (fields & values) of a specific hash key. All of them, without limitation.

When talking about `SORT`, it refers to actions on `List`s, `Set`s and `Sorted Set`s.
It returns members of these structures in an ordered manner, as dictated by `SORT`'s parameters. See [SORT documentation](http://redis.io/commands/sort).

Comment: is there a way to have a results limit when retrieving from a hash then??

Comment: No and in essence there's no need to. An hash key is intended to hold something like an "object", something with a few (up to 20 or so) properties, not to hold an ever growing structure like list or set. Please examine your business rules, you might find that what you need is another Redis structure.